# DirectorySearcher null comparison in filters

Tags: active-directory

I am trying to find LDAP objects which don't have any value in their "manager" property. What should be the filter string? I am trying with this to no avail:

```
"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(manager=NULL))"
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!(manager=*)))
```

`!` is the "not" operator and `*` is the LDAP wildcard so the above will do a search for any entry that doesn't have a value set for the `manager`-attribute.